# Having Arduino connect to my Ubuntu server

Tags: sql-server, arduino

I have an arduino client which reads rfid tags. I would like it to connect to my Ubuntu server , get access to the database so as to allow or not allow permissions. How do i make the connection possible using the socket i have within the server. Any ideas will be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked already here: [Can I put items in a MySQL database directly from my Arduino?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456908/can-i-put-items-in-a-mysql-database-directly-from-my-arduino/9457467#9457467)

One of the answers looks promising.

I suggest you look at this [mysql arduino connector](http://drcharlesbell.blogspot.com/2013/04/introducing-mysql-connectorarduino_6.html) to see if it does what you need.