# MySQL Data to Arduino

Tags: php, mysql, arduino, processing

What would be a proper way of getting stored information from a MySQL database inserted into an Arduino script?  Also, would the Arduino board be able to connect to the database via the Arduino WiFi Shield, or would there be something else needed?

Comment: http://drcharlesbell.blogspot.ro/2013/04/introducing-mysql-connectorarduino_6.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456908/can-i-put-items-in-a-mysql-database-directly-from-my-arduino

Answer (score 1):

I'm using an Arduino Mega with an Ethernet shield.

I send variables in a POST statement for the query in the HTTP request header from the Arduino.  A PHP script retrieves the data and puts it into the HTML code that the server will return.

I used the client example provided with the Arduino software as a starting point for my program.